# How to create a websocket that points to a vnc server using java?

Tags: java, websocket, vnc

I have used novnc websockify(implemented using python). how to create a WebSocket server that points to the vnc server port?

Answer (score 0):

Try this guide from [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_a_WebSocket_server_in_Java) to write a WebSocket server in Java.